# How to redirect every web request to local server programmatically in chrome or stock browser?

Tags: android, proxy

I need monitor and block websites in realtime(It's for a parental control app). I did some research and found this app [qustodio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qustodio.qustodioapp). It seems like they are using internal proxy server to do it. Every time browser request a web site it going to localhost:port address and redirect to that site(It does not work in incongnito mode in that app). I checked proxy settings in chrome but i couldn't find any proxy settings in chrome://net-internals.

I need to know how to redirect every web request to that local server programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by redirecting programmatically in chrome?

Comment: I mean in that app every web request is going through local server. I can see that because url is changing to localhost and then again to real url. I want to know how to archive that programmatically (By another app) in android stock browser or chrome. Is that clear?

Answer (score 0):

Although its too late, I figured out qustodio, does not redirect the web request to any local server, instead it uses the [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) of android to monitor the chrome browser and fetches the url's from there to filter out the blocked content for children.